How to include assembly view model space in .NET project in Visual Studio 2022
I am trying to include
xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:ViewModelsSamples.Axes.LabelsFormat2;assembly=ViewModelsSamples"

in the UserControl instance. But, I'm unable to include it. What could be the reason?
How can I include it in the easiest way?
